# Как парсить XML документ с вложенными элементами?

Tags: sql, xml, парсер, oracle, oracle11g

Выполняю запрос:

```
with demo as(
select XMLType('<items>
                  <item id="1745212" template="Бокс распределительный">
                    <p60226>DKC</p60226>
                    <p60227>R5PKEB2V81713B4P</p60227>
                    <p69317>Бокс распределительный</p69317>
                  </item>
                  <item id="1745213" template="Бокс распределительный">
                    <p60226>DKC</p60226>
                    <p60227>R5PKEB2V817144P</p60227>
                    <p69317>Бокс распределительный малый</p69317>
                    </item>
                  </items>'
                    ) xml from dual)
select 
         extractvalue(value(dt1),'/item/@id') id,
         dt2.column_value.getrootelement() property_name,
         extractValue(value(dt2),'/*') value
from 
     demo s,
     table(XMLSequence(s.xml.extract('/items/item'))) dt1,
     table(XMLSequence(s.xml.extract('/items/item/*'))) dt2
```

Ожидаю на выходе 6 строк вида: `item_id, property_name, value`, а получаю 12.
Т.е., для каждого `item_id` все 6 `value`, а ожидаю только 3, к нему относящиеся.

И вроде причина понятна, но вот как исключить дублирование?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Таблицы `dt1` и `dt2` выбирают из одного и того же документа `s.xml`, и как следствие, декартово произведение этих двух таблиц.

Функции: `XMLSequence`, `extractvalue`, `getrootelement` в 11.2.0.1 [объявлены устаревшими](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/changes.htm#GUID-27F902E7-911D-49A4-8FAA-BAABB5821E91), они не рекомендуются больше к применению.

Попробуйте с [XMLTable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adxdb/xquery-and-XML-DB.html#GUID-4F83A835-C94B-4D62-999B-111AB5E8A8F1) (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=64a9ba85231f4c88aaff6e2ae51fe39a)):

```
with doc (xml) as (
    select xmlType (
        '<items>
          <item id="1745212" template="Бокс распределительный">
            <p60226>DKC</p60226>
            <p60227>R5PKEB2V81713B4P</p60227>
            <p69317>Бокс распределительный</p69317>
          </item>
          <item id="1745213" template="Бокс распределительный">
            <p60226>DKC</p60226>
            <p60227>R5PKEB2V817144P</p60227>
            <p69317>Бокс распределительный малый</p69317>
            </item>
          </items>') from dual)
select id, name, value 
from doc, xmlTable ('/items/item/*' passing doc.xml columns
    id  number path './../@id',
    name varchar2 (8) path 'name()',
    value varchar2 (64) path 'text()')
```

Результат как и ожидался:

```
        ID NAME     VALUE                           
---------- -------- --------------------------------
   1745212 p60226   DKC                             
   1745212 p60227   R5PKEB2V81713B4P                
   1745212 p69317   Бокс распределительный          
   1745213 p60226   DKC                             
   1745213 p60227   R5PKEB2V817144P                 
   1745213 p69317   Бокс распределительный малый    

6 rows selected.
```